2 units with same function. Calling one or the other depending on unit order in uses clause without qualifying the unit name?
My demo has two units, UnitA and UnitB, each containing a function called MyFunction.
UnitA.pas
unit UnitA;

interface

function MyFunction: string;

implementation

function MyFunction: string;
begin
  Result := 'Function from UnitA';
end;

end.

UnitB.pas
unit UnitB;

interface

function MyFunction: string;

implementation

function MyFunction: string;
begin
  Result := 'Function from UnitB';
end;

end.

In my main program or another unit, I can specify which MyFunction to call by using the unit name as a prefix.
MainProgram.pas
program MainProgram;

uses
  UnitA, UnitB;

begin
  // Calling MyFunction from UnitA
  WriteLn(UnitA.MyFunction);
  // Calling MyFunction from UnitB
  WriteLn(UnitB.MyFunction);
  ReadLn;
end.

I remember I can directly call MyFunction, without any unit prefix, and Delphi will use the function from the last unit written in the uses clause. But this does not work for me using Delphi 11.0.
Did something change, or is my understanding not correct?

Your understanding is correct, and it works like that for me when I test it now in Delphi 11.3.

Can't reproduce in Delphi 12. Your understanding is correct, without qualification the function in the last unit of the uses clause is called, as expected.

Delphi will indeed resolve to the last unit in the uses clause, but relying on that is very, very sloppy and poor programming practice. It can introduce hard to track down bugs and make maintenance extremely difficult. I'd urge you to reconsider doing it, and properly qualify the reference, or don't use functions with the same name at all.

Which error is the compiler raising?
